# Can't store CLLocation objects using geoFire in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cllocation, geofire

CLLocation objects have a structure like:
`"<+10.00000000,+10.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 7/11/19, 10:45:58 PM Eastern Daylight Time"`

i.e, they include the course information as well.
When I try storing my CLLocation object using geoFire like this:

```
geoFire.setLocation(newLocation, forKey: description)
```

My app crashes and I get errors like:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Not a valid GeoFire key: "Apple Campus, Apple Campus, 1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA  95014, United States @ <+37.33233141,-122.03121860> +/- 100.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+37.33213112,-122.02990109> radius 279.37', center:<+37.33213112,-122.02990109>, radius:279.37m)". Characters .#$][/ not allowed in key!'

So I'm guessing that Firebase, that I'm using to store the information isn't happy about all the course information, but I don't know what to do with it. I tried using geoFire.setLocation with CLLocationCoordinates2D but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Your key has an illegal character

```
.#$][/
```